# Is $\{u_i(x) = |x-\lambda_i|, i=1,n : \lambda_i \ne \lambda_j, \forall i \ne j \}$ linearly dependent?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is $\{ u_i(x) = |x-\lambda_i|, i=1,n : \lambda_i \ne \lambda_j, \forall i \ne j \}$ linearly dependent?

I know there's something to do with $\sum_{i=1}^n {k_i u_i(x)} = 0$, but it's kind of messy.

Could you give any hint? Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: For any $i$ observe that all the terms except $k_iu_i$ are differentiable at $\lambda _i$. If $k_i \neq 0$ you get the  contradiction that the sum $0$ is not differentiable at $\lambda _i$!.

Comment: I get it. Thank you so much!